# How do I get Entity Framework to query the right table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I've got a class defined

```
public class ReportClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ClassIndex { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

}
```

and I set up a dbcontext.

```
public class ReportClassContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ReportClass> ReportClasses { get; set; }
}
```

When I first went to get records, the runtime tells me the database table doesn't exist: I check, and I see that the name of my DbSet doesn't match with the table. I switched the name to match:

```
public class ReportClassContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ReportClass> ReportClassesRealTable { get; set; }
}
```

but it is still querying against the non-existent table.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the table attribute like this:

```
[Table("ReportClassesRealTable")]
public class ReportClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ClassIndex { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

}
```

This tells the EF what the actual table name is for your class, otherwise it attempts to use the plural form of your class name.

Comment: I updated my tag because I realized I'm not using entity framework 4.  My compiler coughs at the [Table] line (incidentally, what is that bracket syntax called?).  Is there an include I need, or is that not supported with this framework version?

Comment: That's an attribute (FYI).  What version of the framework are you using?  Prior to EF4 there was no code first, so you would have to be using an EDMX?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I am using EF4.  Thought this was in .Net 3.5, but it's actually 4.  I am working on too many projects.  Back to the other question, then: why does it cough at the table line?

Comment: The `Table` attribute is part of `System.Component.DataAnnotations` which is in the EntityFramework.dll.  Make sure you have that referenced and the correct using statement.

Comment: Thank you for your patient help!

Answer (score 2):

Let this be there as it is

```
public DbSet<ReportClass> ReportClasses { get; set; }
```

Now overrde the `OnMoedlCreateing` method to tell EF to map this class to a different table using **fluent API**. Add that method to your DBContext class

```
public class ReportClassContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ReportClass> ReportClasses { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Entity<ReportClass>().ToTable("ReportClassesRealTable");
    }
}
```

This tells EF that when you query `ReportClasses` property of your DbContxt object, It will fetch data from teh `ReportClassRealTable` table in your database.